# How to minimise many if conditions in a program to use DRY concept?

Tags: python, if-statement, twitter, tweepy, dry

I have a program that has a few if blocks. I want to use DRY concept as am using same code repeating in those blocks, but different conditions.

Please check the below blocks. I'm using functions in each block that are repeating too. Any idea to code once instead of so many blocks?

```
if today.day == 2: #chose the date until the code is ready
            img_1, img_2, filename = grab_images(images = images, movie_title = movie_title)
            tweet(status = "Will this be a good watch❓ ... Read the plot.", show_update = show_update, img_1= img_1, img_2 = img_2, movie_title = movie_title,api = api)
            time.sleep(2)
            ##Delete images
            os.remove("watchmovies/Images/"+"01"+filename+".jpg") 
            os.remove("watchmovies/Images/"+"02"+filename+".jpg") 
            tweet_reply(status = "w", story = final_story, api = api)
            time.sleep(2)
            second_tweet_reply(status = "w: ", rating_comment = rating_comment, movie_duration = movie_duration, api = api)
            time.sleep(2)
            third_reply_reviews(status = "w", liners = liners, api = api)
            time.sleep(2)

if release_date.day == today.day: #thinking to take this if block out of the program, as release_date if not available will cause issue. 
            img_1, img_2, filename = grab_images(images = images, movie_title = movie_title)
            tweet(status = "-- Is releasing today. Are you excited to watch❓. Here is the plot and rating", img_1= img_1, img_2 = img_2, movie_title = movie_title, api = api)
            time.sleep(2)
            ##Delete images
            os.remove("watchmovies/Images/"+"01"+filename+".jpg") 
            os.remove("watchmovies/Images/"+"02"+filename+".jpg")
            tweet_reply(status = "", story = final_story, api = api)
            time.sleep(2)
            second_tweet_reply(status = " ", rating_comment = rating_comment, movie_duration = movie_duration, api = api)
            time.sleep(2)

movie_releasing, todays_date = strip_date_add(edit_date = str(release_date), day = 1)
if movie_releasing == todays_date:
            img_1, img_2, filename = grab_images(images = images, movie_title = movie_title)
            tweet(status = "-- Was released yesterday. Have you watched it❓ ... read the plot .", img_1= img_1, img_2 = img_2, movie_title = movie_title, api = api)
            time.sleep(2)
            ##Delete images
            os.remove("watchmovies/Images/"+"01"+filename+".jpg") 
            os.remove("watchmovies/Images/"+"02"+filename+".jpg")
            tweet_reply(status = "", story = final_story, api = api)
            time.sleep(2)
            second_tweet_reply(status = " ", rating_comment = rating_comment, movie_duration = movie_duration, api = api)
            time.sleep(2)

movie_releasing, todays_date = strip_date_minus(edit_date = str(release_date), day = 7)
        if movie_releasing == todays_date:
            img_1, img_2, filename = grab_images(images = images, movie_title = movie_title)
            tweet(status = "-- Is releasing next week. Read plot and rating .", img_1= img_1, img_2 = img_2, movie_title = movie_title, api = api)
            time.sleep(2)
            ##Delete images
            os.remove("watchmovies/Images/"+"01"+filename+".jpg") 
            os.remove("watchmovies/Images/"+"02"+filename+".jpg")
            tweet_reply(status = "", story = final_story, api = api)
            time.sleep(2)
            second_tweet_reply(status = " ", rating_comment = rating_comment, movie_duration = movie_duration, api = api)
            time.sleep(2)

movie_releasing, todays_date = strip_date_minus(edit_date = str(release_date), day = 1)
        if movie_releasing == todays_date:
            img_1, img_2, filename = grab_images(images = images, movie_title = movie_title)
            tweet(status = "-- Is releasing tomorrow. Do you plan to watch❓ Here is the plot and rating .", img_1= img_1, img_2 = img_2, movie_title = movie_title, api = api)
            time.sleep(2)
            ##Delete images
            os.remove("watchmovies/Images/"+"01"+filename+".jpg") 
            os.remove("watchmovies/Images/"+"02"+filename+".jpg")
            tweet_reply(status = "", story = final_story, api = api)
            time.sleep(2)
            second_tweet_reply(status = " ", rating_comment = rating_comment, movie_duration = movie_duration, api = api)
            time.sleep(2)
```

The program needs to execute all the tweets in all blocks after meeting its condition.

Answer (score 1):

You did not show the implementation for your tweet functions but maybe you can make a Tweet class to encapsulate the Tweet details. Something along these lines:

```py
class Tweet:
    status = None
    story = None
    img_1 = None
    img_2 = None
    

def process(list_of_tweets):
    img_1, img_2, filename = grab_images(images = images, movie_title = movie_title)
    tweet(list_of_tweets[0])

    os.remove("watchmovies/Images/"+"01"+filename+".jpg") 
    os.remove("watchmovies/Images/"+"02"+filename+".jpg")

    tweet_reply(list_of_tweets[1]))
    second_tweet_reply(list_of_tweets[2]))
    third_reply_reviews(list_of_tweets[3]))


if today.day == 2: #chose the date until the code is ready
    tweets = [
        Tweet(status=..., story=...),
        Tweet(status=..., story=...),
        Tweet(status=..., story=...),
        Tweet(status=..., story=...),
    ]
    process(tweets)
            

if release_date.day == today.day: #thinking to take this if block out of the program, as release_date if not available will cause issue. 
    tweets = [
        Tweet(status=..., story=...),
        Tweet(status=..., story=...),
        Tweet(status=..., story=...),
        Tweet(status=..., story=...),
    ]
    process(tweets)


movie_releasing, todays_date = strip_date_add(edit_date = str(release_date), day = 1)
if movie_releasing == todays_date:
    tweets = [
        Tweet(status=..., story=...),
        Tweet(status=..., story=...),
        Tweet(status=..., story=...),
        Tweet(status=..., story=...),
    ]
    process(tweets)

movie_releasing, todays_date = strip_date_minus(edit_date = str(release_date), day = 7)
    if movie_releasing == todays_date:
        tweets = [
            Tweet(status=..., story=...),
            Tweet(status=..., story=...),
            Tweet(status=..., story=...),
            Tweet(status=..., story=...),
        ]
        process(tweets)


movie_releasing, todays_date = strip_date_minus(edit_date = str(release_date), day = 1)
    if movie_releasing == todays_date:
        tweets = [
            Tweet(status=..., story=...),
            Tweet(status=..., story=...),
            Tweet(status=..., story=...),
            Tweet(status=..., story=...),
        ]
        process(tweets)
```

Comment: Sure. Thanks. I’ll  give it a try. I think it writing a class might help.